# Template for theoretical computer science papers

Tags: templates, arxiv

There's a LaTeX format that I see often used in papers in theoretical computer science, and perhaps in some other branches as well. [Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05520.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05643.pdf) are two examples from today's arXiv:

[image]

[image]

Since it's so widely used, my question is: What is the template for this?

Comment: as usual with arxiv you can download the source in this case a tar archive from http://arxiv.org/format/1603.05520v1 which shows that it is just `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is from [arXiv](http://arxiv.org), you can peruse their [submission information](http://arxiv.org/help/submit), specifically **Formats for text of submission**. Here they list their preferred [submission format using TeX](http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex). Quoting from the aforementioned link(s):

> #### Submissions are automatically processed
>
> Your (La)TeX, AMS(La)TeX, or PDFLaTeX submission will be processed automatically by our AutoTeX software.
>
> This is a complex task, and the processing does not always lead to the desired or expected results. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> All TeX, LaTeX, and PDFLaTeX submissions receive the arXiv watermark, including the canonical identifier, version number, primary classification, and a link back to the correct version on the arXiv site. [...]

It is clear that the "template" output is generated in-house, and therefore not readily available. Each arXiv is available for download, but it has been *constructed* during the AutoTeX process.

Comment: This is wrong.  The only thing added by the arXiv is the watermark.  The overall format (margins, font, section heading style, etc.) is determined by the document class and template chosen by the authors.  As  David Carlisle mentioned, you can download the original TeX file from any given submission and just look at what was used.

Comment: @JessRiedel: Sure. For you, the watermark does not form part of the template. For me, it does.